# Handling by objects with properties instead of direct column values in PHP and MySQL (getters and setters)

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to OOP in PHP, and i want to know how to handle MySQL logic through objects and properties instead of using direct column values by using getters and setters:

```
 $stmt = $this->db_connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM product_list where type="dvd" ORDER BY ID');
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt2 = $this->db_connect()->prepare('SELECT size FROM dvd');
        $stmt2->execute();
while($size = $stmt2->fetch()){
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo '<div class="product">'.
            '<input type="checkbox" class="delete-checkbox" name="check[]" value ="'. $row['ID'].'">';
            echo '<p>'.$row['sku']. '<br>' .$row['name']. '<br>'.$row['price'].'$'.' <br>'.$size['size'].'MB'.'</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } 
     }
```

Comment: You should use the MODE parameter for the fetch() method. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php then, $row would be an object instead of an array.